# How to deploy a jekyll site locally with css, js and background images included?

Tags: css, image, static, publish, jekyll

I've been trying to load my octopress site (based on jekyll) to my local network.  There is no server, I just want it available locally on a shared folder.

Every time i deploy it to a local folder the css and js and background image links are broken.

The available options such as rsync, github and heroku all require ssh's and passwords.  This can be found here: http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/

Is there a rake option that helps with this?

### SOLVED:

Kikito, Thank you very much for the guidance.

I just implemented it and forked a git repository. There is one problem, though. I have used this technique to host the same site on Dropbox Public, a local directory and a web host. I had to add an extra / and the slashes add up as links are clicked. Here is the repo and dropbox link:

https://github.com/originalsurfmex/jekyll-relative-bootstrap

Everything works as you say, but I think that if you or others glance at the partials and links in the layouts you will have a better idea.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Automatic way:

**for css/js file:**

```
{% assign lvl = page.url | append:'X' | split:'/' | size %}
{% capture relative %}{% for i in (3..lvl) %}../{% endfor %}{% endcapture %}

<link href="{{ relative }}css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="{{ relative }}scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

**for other files:**

in _config.yml set

```
url: http://www.yourdomain.com
```

add canonical link element:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ site.url }}{{ page.url }}" />
```

in one of your js file, add:

```
var relative = null;
if (location.protocol==='file:') {
    relative = Array($('link[rel="canonical"]').attr('href').match(/\//g).length-2).join('../');
    if (relative == '') relative = './';
}
function to_relative(link, index) {
    if (!relative) return link;
    var hash = link ? link.match(/#.*$/) : null;
    if (hash) link = link.replace(/#.*$/, '');
    return link?(link.replace(/^\//, relative)+(index?(link.substr(-1)=='/'?'index.html':''):'')+(hash?hash[0]:'')):null;
}

$(function(){
    if (relative) {
        $('a').attr('href', function(a,b){return to_relative(b, true);});
        $('img').attr('src', function(a,b){return to_relative(b, false);});
    }
});
```

for other aspects, use jQuery to manipulate them.

Comment: Wow. That is incredible. I was able to use just your first trick ("for css/js file") for everything, including `<a>` and `<img>`.

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that you are using absolute paths to get to some of your resources. If you want to deploy the site anywhere in the network, then you need to make those relative.

In my case, what I do is to define an (optional) setting called `root` in the pages/posts that need it, pointing to the "relative root" of the project. For example, on a page located in `about/index.html`, the root will be `../`, since there is only one level "up":

```
---
title: My Page title
root: "../"
---
```

Pages further away in the directories will need more dots: `../../`, `../../../`, and so on. Pages in the root folder (like index.html) don't need a root.

Then I use that setting to generate *all* the paths.

If I'm on the page or post itself, and I need to refer to a local image or another page, use `page.root` or `post.root`:

```
<img src="{{ post.root }}images/happy.png" />
<a href="{{ post.root }}2010/01/01/another_post>Relative link to another post</a>
```

It's possible to make the reference directly (`../images/happy.png`) but this works better when you are creating the site, and you are still unsure about the definitive paths of each page.

I have all the css and js included in one partial file inside _includes. It creates a variable called `root` to make sure it works with both pages and posts:

```
{% capture root %}{% if page.root %}{{ page.root }}{% else %}{{ post.root }}{% endif %}{%endcapture%}

<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ root }}js/jquery-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ root }}/css/style.css" />
```

That's pretty much it.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that `<script>` is not a self-closing tag. Copy-pasted the example and everything after `<script />` disappeared. Yes, I've made the same mistake several times, but this time I thought it was a jekyll error that borked the output ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you can live with having to generate your site for a specific folder, using the html `<base />` tag may be more straightforward. With all asset paths relative to your root folder, add the following to your default layout:

```
<base href="{{ site.baseurl }}" />
```

Then use the `jekyll --base-url <folder> <folder>` to deploy your jekyll site to `<folder>` with the `baseurl` set up correctly.

Note that this also works without changes with the built-in WEBrick server. Start with `jekyll --server` and do not specify a custom `--base-url`.

**Update:** as gimpf points out in the comment, this will not work as expected with anchor links. Those will point to the base URL instead of the current page. There are [workarounds](https://rogerkeays.com/blog/using-base-href-with-anchors) using JavaScript, e.g. rewrite anchor hrefs with jQuery:

```
$().ready(function() {
  $("a[href^='\#']").each(function(){
    this.href=location.href.split("#")[0]+'#'+this.href.substr(this.href.indexOf('#')+1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please be advised that when using this, anchor-links are also relative to the base-href.  So instead of using `<a href="#anchor"...` you need to use `<a href="path/to/page#anchor...`.

Answer (score 3):

There is an [issue on the Jekyll's github](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/issues/26) that deals with this. Putting `_config.yml`:

```
url: "<your domain>"
```

and then using `{{ site.url }}` will return the url. So for example, to refer to the `/css/styles.css` file from a page's header:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en-us">  
  <head>
      <...>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.url }}/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
      <...>
  </head>
  <body>
     ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked wonderfully for me! I've always wondered how to set the site.url.

Answer (score 3):

*Alternate Answer* -

I had a similar requirement of a locally hosted static html so that I could distribute it to other computers without a web server and have it read from the filesystem by a regular browser.

Rather than fiddle with arcane path syntax in various places -- although it can be done evidenced by other answers in this thread -- I instead chose a workaround by publishing the site to my localhost:4000 served up by Jekyll as per usual, and then used the `wget` utility to download a static copy of the static website which could then be opened and navigated from the filesystem with a standard web browser. `wget` will do the hard work of making the paths relative for you.

This is the `wget` command I use -

```
wget \
 --recursive \
 --no-clobber \
 --page-requisites \
 --html-extension \
 --convert-links \
 --restrict-file-names=windows \
 --domains localhost http://localhost:4000
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the path to your images/JS/CSS will need a slight adjustment. Try using a path that points to the generated folder.

For example:

```
<img src="/_site/images/foobar.jpg" />
```

Comment: That sort of worked, except some links still ended up with a backslash and i had to adjust the is there a way to set everything to be relevant so that i can copy the folder anywhere on the local network?

Comment: I ended up using kikitos {{ root }} variable suggestion, so: <<img src="{{ root }}/_site/images/foobar.jpg" /> ended up fixing it.