# How to make automatic prefixes for relative urls calling css assets from any (sub)folder?

Tags: jekyll

I would like to be able to define the links of my website as relative paths. I think it is more reliable in case the site is moved later for instance.

For the moment, my links are absolute, so I have:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.url }}/assets/css/app.css" />`

in `_includes/header.html` called by `_layouts/page.html` to generate the pages of my website.

A first approach would be to put

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/app.css" />`

but it works only for pages in the root.

Another attempt would be to put

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/app.css" />`

but it works only for pages in a subfolder the root.

In fact we need to use as many `../` as needed to go back to the root. Would it be possible to automatically count it (maybe based on the `page.url` variable? I am not sure how to do it nor where to put such a script.

I am aware of the answer of [kikito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312586/kikito) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985081/how-to-deploy-a-jekyll-site-locally-with-css-js-and-background-images-included) but it is needed to manually declare the correct path to the `root` variable of the page in the metadata when creating it. I would like to automate this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have issues with [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14254928/230449) to the question you linked to? That solution works for me.

In the head of my layout file I include the code:

```
{% capture lvl %}{{ page.url | append:'index.html' | split:'/' | size }}{% endcapture %}
{% capture relative %}{% for i in (3..lvl) %}../{% endfor %}{% endcapture %}
```

Then my resources can be set up as:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ relative }}assets/css/combined.min.css">`

This results in the correct number of `../` parts being added. The "assets" directory in this example is in the root of my site.

Comment: I was afraid this solution would not work if the website was later moved at another level since the `3` is hardcoded. But I realized with your answer that I can change the `3`to what is needed at the generation depending on what has been assigned to `site.url`. Thank you!