# Relative Links in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm having a bit of an issue with links in Jekyll.

For example, I have a post in the folder:

```
file:///C:/Users/My%20Name/Documents/jekyll_site/2014-10-25-Workshop.html
```

When I use `jekyll build` the post is inserted into this folder:
    file:///C:/Users/My%20Name/Documents/jekyll_site/_site/2014/10/25/Workshop.html

Within the post template, I use this simple code to go to the next or previous page:

```
{% if page.previous.url %}  
<p class="previousEntry blueButton"> <a href="{{page.previous.url}}">&#60;&#60; Go to older entry</a></p>
{% else %}
<p class="previousEntry blueButton">&#60;&#60;  Go to older entry</p>
{% endif %}
```

When I run `jekyll serve`, everything looks okay at `http://localhost:4000`,
however, when I look at the code generated after `jekyll build` it looks like this:

```
<p class="previousEntry blueButton"> <a href="/2013/04/12/FirstVisit.html">&#60;&#60;   Go to older entry</a></p>
<p class="nextEntry blueButton"><a href="/2014/07/09/OfficialMeeting.html">Go to newer entry &#62;&#62;</a></p>
<p class="backToNews blueButton"><a href="news.html">Go back to main news page</a></p>
```

And, for example, when I click on "Go to older entry", I am directed to `file:///C:/2013/04/12/FirstVisit.html` (which leads to a "this page can't be found" page) instead of `file:///C:/Users/My%20Name/Documents/jekyll_site/_site/2013/04/12/FirstVisit.html` (which is the current location of the page)

Will this cause an issue when I try to upload it to the web server? If so, how do I make it so this relative link will direct the user to the place I want once I upload it to the web server?

Comment: Here you have the answer from a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14254928/2491604

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A relative link like `/folder/file.html` is relative to a host, like `http://host.tld`.

`host + relative path = http://host.tld/folder/file.html`.

As `Jekyll serve` sets the host's root folder at `file:///C:/somePath/_site/` this finally resolve to

`root folder + relative path = file:///C:/somePath/_site/folder/file.html` and this is the right path.

Here you're talking about the file protocol (file://), the "host" here is `file:///C:` and the relative path `/2013/04/12/FirstVisit.html` is resolved to

`host + relative path = file:///C:/2013/04/12/FirstVisit.html` which leads to a page not found.

The real problem here is that you're talking about a page opened from the file explorer. You've clicked on a html page which is opened using the file protocol, not the http protocol.

Make sure that you open your site with `http://localhost:4000` by pasting this url in your browser, not by clicking on a page in the file explorer.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to get it to work locally:
- Double-clicked the index and observed the address bar in the browser. For my current project it is: `file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/blog/blog/_site/index.html`
- Opened the `_config.yml` file and changed it from `baseurl:""`, which is exactly what was in the address bar before the `index.html` end-part, to    `baseurl:"file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/blog/blog/_site/"`
-Built the site again in the terminal

This works locally. When I will upload the site to a folder on my web host, I'll change again the `baseurl` in a similar matter.